# What are the possible bugs that cause slow response (sometimes but not all the time) for a websocket connection?

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, protocol-buffers, uwsgi

I know my question's topic is too broad. Please ask on anything that can help you find my question more answerable.

CONTEXT: The web architecture is like the following description:

- A front-end view generated by Django View, accessible through ngInx
  server. The javascript is responsible for send/receive data to/from
  web socket app.
- A web socket app written in python that makes use of uwsgi server as its communication protocol.
- The web socket app communicates with a remote server(C++) using topics and rabbitMQ.
- The data is serialized using protobuf.
- Version: Django 1.7.7, Python 2.7.5, rabbitMQ 3.4.4, nginx 1.6.2 and uwsgi 2.0.10

PROBLEM: Right now I'm facing a bug that is very nightmarish in the sense that it is hard to find out the bug's root cause, it happens during production and does not always appear.
Sometimes the web socket is responding very slow (1 or 2 minutes) when the user clicks on buttons while the rest of the time the response time is in milliseconds.

I suspect that the bug is due to configuration of the architecture rather than the code itself since the bug only appears sometimes. Also, I can edit the question to add in code if you think I need to. The front-end has a heartbeat back-and-forth connection with the websocket app so internet connection is ruled out. Any idea on how to debug this?

Thank for reading this question. :)

Comment: Wireshark? or some other lower level packet analyzer. Also some other monitoring tools at each end, ea. a cpu(nginx worker) might be going high due to a blocking call. And a pingtool for the socket link (maybe lan saturation). Check uwsgi sources with nginx 1.9.2 to see if there are any bug fixes.

Comment: I updated nginx from 1.6.2 to 1.8 and the result is positive, the bug has not appeared for one day. But im still not sure if the bug is gone. anw, good exp, thanks @itpp13

Comment: @itpp13 Can you elaborate more on "cpu(nginx worker) might be going high due to a blocking call"? This is because I read that nginx is designed with a non-blocking model in mind. Any additional resource is very welcome.

Comment: This not easy to explain, but for example with a backend which does not return a call and thereby blocks the worker sending it, to get more technical see http://nginx-win.ecsds.eu/download/ngxLuaDB-1.1.zip and the geoip examples in /conf which has a blocking and non-blocking Lua sample. To keep it simple, anything nginx itself can deal with is non-blocking, anything it has to pass outside (this can be an added on module as well) can be non-blocking but can easily block as well.